# JOIN the record with the most similar name with each row from multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-order-by, limit

**Platform:** PostgreSQL

**Tables**:

```
shortlist:  name (text), city (text)...
data1:      name (text), ranking (integer), score1 (double)...
data2:      name (text), ranking (integer), score1 (double)...
data3:      name (text), ranking (integer), score1 (double)...
data4:      name (text), ranking (integer), score1 (double)...
```

There is a limited number of data tables of similar format.

---

I would like to join each row in `shortlist` with the row in each `data` table that has the most similar name determined by `similarity(shortlist.name, data#.name)`.

---

Pseudo code of the same idea:

```
for each s_row in shortlist:
    select shortlist.*
    join (SELECT data1.*, similarity(s_row.name, data1.name) AS sim FROM data1 ORDER BY sim DESC LIMIT 1)
    join (SELECT data2.*, similarity(s_row.name, data2.name) AS sim FROM data2 ORDER BY sim DESC LIMIT 1)
    join (SELECT data3.*, similarity(s_row.name, data3.name) AS sim FROM data3 ORDER BY sim DESC LIMIT 1)
    join (SELECT data4.*, similarity(s_row.name, data4.name) AS sim FROM data4 ORDER BY sim DESC LIMIT 1)
```

---

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Comment: A given record in the result set could include bits and pieces from all four tables.  This looks like bad database design to me.

Comment: What if the similarity in data1 is less then the one in data2? Which name do you want to see? Or do you always want to see all rows from the "data" tables? that are "similar" to the one in the shortlist table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What I intended to do is to find all the different rankings, etc of shortlisted items from each data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are after but something like this:

```
select s.name, 
       d1.name as d1_name, 
       d2.name as d2_name
from shortlist s 
  left join lateral (
    SELECT data1.*, similarity(s.name, data1.name) AS sim 
    FROM data1 
    ORDER BY sim 
    DESC LIMIT 1
  ) d1 on true
  left join lateral (
    SELECT data2.*, similarity(s.name, data2.name) AS sim 
    FROM data2 
    ORDER BY sim DESC 
    LIMIT 1
  ) d2 on true
```

You want an outer join (`left join`) for each table because otherwise you would not see anything if there is no match in at least one of the tables.